# Setting up mailing in Hudson CI

Tags: hudson

Here is the problem - after the next assembly system sends some continuous integration is likely to default notification, which refers to the control panel with CI information about the success / failure. For example, after a letter arrives from commit theme

**Hudson build is back to normal**,

which contains the string -

**See [http://ХХ.ХХ.ХХ.ХХ:.../1457/](http://%D0%A5%D0%A5.%D0%A5%D0%A5.%D0%A5%D0%A5.%D0%A5%D0%A5:.../1457/)**

It is possible to configure Hudson, so that instead of this message came references to deploy?

Comment: No offence intended, but did you use Google Translate here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with the email plugin. See [email plugin configuration](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin):

> Advanced configuration
>
> To see the advanced configuration for the
> plugin, click the "Advanced" button.  This section allows you to
> specify recipients for each type of email trigger.  By default, the
> only trigger configured is the "Failure" trigger.  To add more
> triggers, select one from the dropdown, and it will be added to the
> list.  Once you have added a trigger, you have several options.  If
> you click "?" (question mark) next to a trigger, it will tell you what
> conditions must be met for it to send an email.
>
> - Send to Recipient List - Check this checkbox if you would like to have the email sent to the "Global Recipient List" configured above.
> - Send to Committers - Check this checkbox to send the email to anyone who checked in code for the last build.  The plugin will
>   generate an email address based on the committer's id and an appended
>   "default email suffix" from Hudson's global configuration page.  For
>   instance, if a change was committed by someone with an id
>   "first.last", and the default email suffix is "@somewhere.com", then
>   an email will be sent to "first.last@somewhere.com"
> - More Configuration - Configure properties at a per-trigger level.
>
>   - Recipient List - A comma (and whitespace) separated list of email address that should receive this email if it is triggered.  This list
>     is appended to the "Global Recipient List" above.
>   - Subject - Specify the subject line of the selected email.
>   - **Content - Specify the body of the selected email.**
> - Remove - Click the delete button next to an email trigger to remove it from the configured triggers list.